Why are required fields not being respected in my JSON schema?
I'm trying to teach myself JSON schema validation (in C#) step-by-step for a company project and I've reached the point of learning field requirement, but the results I'm seeing don't seem to respect my 'required field' specification. I could use a hand figuring out why.
Here's the schema I'm saved into a file called "TestJsonSchema.txt"...
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
    "title": "Person",
    "description": "Simple person for testing schema validation",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "FirstName": {
            "description": "The person's first name.",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "LastName": {
            "description": "The person's last name.",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Age": {
            "description": "Age of the person in years.",
            "type": "integer",
            "exclusiveMinimum": 18
        }
    },
    "required": ["LastName", "Age"]
}

... and here is the test program...
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;

   public class Person
   {
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
   }

   public class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           string schemaFilePath = @"C:\testtest\TestJsonSchema.txt";
           JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(File.ReadAllText(schemaFilePath));

           // Should be valid.
           Person fullPerson = new Person()
           {
               FirstName = "John",
               LastName = "Doe",
               Age = 25
           };

           // I expect this to be valid as there's a LName and age.
           Person noFNamePerson = new Person()
           {
               LastName = "Teller",
               Age = 30
           };

           // I expect this to be invalid as there's no LName
           Person noLNamePerson = new Person()
           {
               FirstName = "Madonna",
               Age = 56
           };

           // I expect this to be valid as both teh LastName and Age are populated.
           Person BlankFNamePerson = new Person()
           {
               FirstName = "",
               LastName = "Mason",
               Age = 49
           };

           // I honestly don't know whether this should or shouldn't be valid since
           // the required LastName is blank.
           // (My first time with these validity checks.  Hence all these test cases)
            Person BlankLNamePerson = new Person()
           {
               FirstName = "Cher",
               LastName = "",
               Age = 120
           };
           
           JObject fullObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fullPerson));
           JObject noFNameObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(noFNamePerson));
           JObject noLNameObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(noLNamePerson));
           JObject blankFNameObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BlankFNamePerson));
           JObject blankLNameObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BlankLNamePerson));

           bool fullValid = fullObj.IsValid(schema);               // Coming up true.  EXPECTED
           bool noFNameValid = noFNameObj.IsValid(schema);         // Coming up false.  !! WHY?? !!
           bool noLNameValid = noLNameObj.IsValid(schema);         // Coming up false.  EXPECTED
           bool blankFNameValid = blankFNameObj.IsValid(schema);   // Coming up true.  EXPECTED
           bool blankLNameValid = blankLNameObj.IsValid(schema);   // Coming up true.  NOT SURE IF CORRECT.

           // THESE ARE MY QUICK AND DIRTY WAYS OF FINDING OUT WHAT IS AND ISN'T VALID.
           Console.WriteLine("Full person is valid: " + fullValid);
           Console.WriteLine("No First Name person is valid: " + noFNameValid);
           Console.WriteLine("No Last Name person is valid: " + noLNameValid);
           Console.WriteLine("Blank First Name person is valid: " + blankFNameValid);
           Console.WriteLine("Blank Last Name person is valid: " + blankLNameValid);            
       }
   }

For the sake of strict scrutiny, here are the converted JSON for both the No-First-Name Person and the Blank-First-Name Person...
No-First-Name (Coming up Invalid)
{"FirstName":null,"LastName":"Teller","Age":30}

Blank-First-Name (Coming up Valid)
{"FirstName":"","LastName":"Mason","Age":49}

So, long story short:
Why is the no-first-name person invalid even though it has the required fields?  Also, is the presence of a blank string, as in the Blank-First-Name JSON, enough to satisfy a required-field?
NOTE These valid/invalid results are exactly the same as when I remove the "required" item from the schema.  That's why I created this question in the first place; I'm not sure if I'm using it improperly.
Thanks.

For the record, "required" in your JSON schema just means "the property is present". It has nothing to do with the property's value.

Regarding your line
bool noFNameValid = noFNameObj.IsValid(schema);         // Coming up false.  !! WHY?? !!

You try to validate noFNamePerson
JObject noFNameObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(noFNamePerson));

Which is defined as below
// I expect this to be valid as there's a LName and age.
Person noFNamePerson = new Person()
{
    LastName = "Teller",
    Age = 30
};

It fails this rule with error:

Invalid type. Expected String but got Null.

for FirstName
This could be easily investigated if you would use this method overload:
bool noFNameValid = noFNameObj.IsValid(schema, out IList<ValidationError> errors);

which shows what is wrong:

Regarding another line
bool blankLNameValid = blankLNameObj.IsValid(schema);   // Coming up true.  NOT SURE IF CORRECT.

This is for object defined as below:
// I honestly don't know whether this should or shouldn't be valid since
// the required LastName is blank.
// (My first time with these validity checks.  Hence all these test cases)
Person BlankLNamePerson = new Person()
{
    FirstName = "Cher",
    LastName = "",
    Age = 120
};

Empty value is still a value, not its absence, that's wy it passes. If you would define you JSON validation as below:
"LastName": {
    "minLength": 1,
    "description": "The person's last name.",
    "type": "string"
}

it would fail the validation.

Thank you very much, Michal.  This covers pretty much everything I needed.

This is not correct JSON Schema behavior.

You try to validate noFNamePerson


JObject noFNameObj =
JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(noFNamePerson));
Which is defined as below


// I expect this to be valid as there's a LName and age.
Person noFNamePerson = new Person()
{
LastName = "Teller",
Age = 30
};
It fails this rule with error:


Invalid type. Expected String but got Null.


for FirstName


Your schema says required: [LastName, Age]
If you don't pass FirstName, this is still a valid instance.  JSON Schema is a constraints based language, meaning only the constraints APPLIED are validated. Anything else is ignored
The only constraint you have applied to FirstName is type: string, IF and ONLY IF this property is defined in the instance.
properties: 
  FirstName:
    type: string

It looks like your json is incorrectly serializing all the properties and instantiating FirstName as null.
You  might try using annotations to inform the serializer the behavior you actually want.
public class Person
   {
       [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
       public string FirstName? { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)] = string.Empty;
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
       public int Age { get; set; }
   }


